# Oracle Database Login Issue SQL developer - After multiple uninstall

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, oracle19c

***Install 1 -***
Initially Installed oracle 19c version with a virtual account.
Had issue with the password while trying to access DB, saying it was invalid.
I decided reinstalling thinking might have messed up during setting of the password.
(was quite sure i was typing the right password but still)
Steps -

> Step 1

- Removed Oracle from PATH variable

> Step 2

- Deleted Registry Files from
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQr51.png)

> Step 3

- Deleted this as well
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkTWc.png)
  **

> Step 4

- Deleted Oracle_base folder (Not oracle Intallation folder which was the actual extracted folder form the zip file, installed from oracle site/ setup folder)**

> Step 5

- Deleted temp Files, deleted C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ Oracle related folder, C:\Users\Oracle also.

***Install 2 -***
But when i reinstalled oracle 19c back i faced the issue like -

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
when trying to connect to the DB.
```

And My **`TNSPing`** command in command prompt was unable to link a proper service to the Listener

I found out that my **sqlNet.ora had `value = NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)**`
and **tnsnames.ora =

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )**
```

Which seemed fine as per my findings from internet.

***Install 3 -***
I decided to reinstall Oracle 19c again. This time i deleted the installation folder also
i.e.
Followed the same steps to uninstall as in ***Install 1 -*** with only step 4 as -
**

> Step 4

- Deleted both Oracle_base folder And oracle Intallation folder which was the actual extracted folder form the zip file, installed from oracle site/ setup folder**

This time i got
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
01017. 00000 -  "invalid username/password; logon denied"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Vendor code 1017
```

### ***Install 4 -***

Finally decide to install oracle 12c.
again getting
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
01017. 00000 -  "invalid username/password; logon denied"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Vendor code 1017
```

Can some please help me establish a connection to the oracle DB. That's all i ask.
:(

Comment: if you were connecting as SYS in SQL Developer, AND you didn't set the connection properties to 'AS SYSDBA' - you would get that exact error message, even if you had the right password. You could also try SYSTEM, with the same password.

Comment: I was able to login using username 'SYS AS SYSDBA'.

Before login in 

**1.** opened command Prompt 
**2.** `C:\Users\arvormfc>sqlplus /nolog`

**3.** `SQL> connect / as sysdba;
Connected.`
**4** `SQL> alter user ORCL identified by newpass;
alter user ORCL identified by newpass
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'ORCL' does not exist`

**5** `SQL> alter user sys identified by newpass;
User altered.`

Answer (score 1):

The sys or system password supplied at the pint of installation should be able to give you access to the database.
or you can follow these steps to reset the SYS password.

Run SQL*PLUS using Run SQL Command Line in Oracle Database 11g
Connect to Oracle Database as SYSDBA as follows:

**SQL>connect as sysdba**

It will ask you to enter username. Enter **SYS** as username.
When prompted for a password, **enter change_on_install**, which is the password for SYS account.
Once you are connected to SYS account, you get adminstrator privileges. So, you can use

ALTER USER command to change password of SYSTEM account as follow:

SQL> **ALTER USER system IDENTIFIED BY oracle;**

The above command changes password of SYSTEM account to oracle. Be careful passwords are case-sensitive.
That's all you have to do to change password for SYSTEM account when you forget the password.
I hope thi shelps

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
`Enter user-name: SYS
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER`

Next i tried with SYSDBA and password as : change_on_install
`Enter user-name: SYSDBA
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`